# IE8 is not handling 301 redirect from non-www page

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

In firefox, everything works great: http://www.laddercapital.com works fine, and http://laddercapital.com redirects to the www site.

In IE8, mysteriously, http://laddercapital.com displays an error "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage"

I checked the server headers here: http://www.stepforth.com/resources/server-header-checker-tool - and it reports a 301 redirect.

What is going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong on my end. Configured correctly.

```
buggedtech:~ icasimpan$ curl -I http://laddercapital.com  
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Length: -1 
Location: http://www.laddercapital.com/  
Date: Sat, 29 Jan 2011 00:45:12 GMT 
Server: Apache


buggedtech:~ icasimpan$ curl -I http://www.laddercapital.com 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: -1 
Date: Sat, 29 Jan 2011 00:45:23 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Pingback: http://www.laddercapital.com/xmlrpc.php
```

Hope that helps,

Ismael Casimpan :)

Answer (score 1):

IE 8 works fine here, it gets redirected to www are you sure it's not a local issue?

Comment: Thanks for checking, sorry for the false alarm!  I think it was related to the Bing search bar in IE8... and since not a lot of people use it... I decided not to worry.